# Filter the rows of a 2d array to optimally keep rows so that a column's values appear in descending order

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering

I am solving a formula for MLM website for distributing their members a commission.

I have a two dimensional array in PHP `$directors`, which is as below:

```
[
    ["user_id" => 10, "directors_count" => 6],
    ["user_id" => 11, "directors_count" => 2],
    ["user_id" => 12, "directors_count" => 5],
    ["user_id" => 13, "directors_count" => 1],
    ["user_id" => 14, "directors_count" => 1],
    ["user_id" => 15, "directors_count" => 2],
    ["user_id" => 16, "directors_count" => 1],
    ["user_id" => 17, "directors_count" => 0],
]
```

`$directors` array will be used to generate an new array called `$final_array` which would extract data from `$directors` array `$directors[''directors_count]` key wise (DESC wise) but in straight manner.

I want `$directors` array to be extracted like

**highest directors_count** >> **next highest directors_count** >> **next highest directors_count**

without going back with array's index, unwanted indexes would get deleted.

as mentioned in bellow image, all the indexes without highlighted (with red) would get deleted

[image]

so the `$final_array` would look like something below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 10
        [directors_count] => 6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 12
        [directors_count] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 15
        [directors_count] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 16
        [directors_count] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 17


        [directors_count] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: do you have any condition to also grab the highest user_id while sorting by directors_count descending order?

Comment: _“all the indexes without highlighted (with red) would get deleted”_ - based on what exactly do they get deleted? (Btw., if you want to _remove_ certain elements from an array, you can hardly call that _sorting_ any more. Sorting does not remove elements.)

Comment: So, how would you know which ones to delete? Do you just want to keep the one duplicate with the highest count? You can't just say "I want to delete these", you need to tell us the condition. Either way, you should actually start by making some attempts to solve this yourself

Comment: Added an answer for you, hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you for sure. Check out the below methods.

- array_column
- array_unique
- array_multisort
- array_intersect_key

  ```
  array_multisort(array_column($array, 'directors_count'), SORT_DESC,
                  array_column($array, 'user_id'),      SORT_DESC,
                  $array);

  $tempArr = array_unique(array_column($array, 'directors_count'));
  $final_array = array_intersect_key($array, $tempArr);                
  print_r($final_array);
  ```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 10 [directors_count] => 6 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 12 [directors_count] => 5 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [user_id] => 15 [directors_count] => 2 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [user_id] => 16 [directors_count] => 1 ) 
 [7] => Array ( [user_id] => 17 [directors_count] => 0 ) 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/JV0Kn

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding of the task, you don't need more than once cycle.

- Establish a temporary variable with a number below the lowest possible number in the `directors_count` column.
- Iterate the array in reverse.
- Push qualifying rows into the front of the array and update the temporary value to the encountered `directors_count` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Pf8Oa))

```
$result = [];
$toBeat = -1;
for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    if ($array[$i]['directors_count'] > $toBeat) {
        array_unshift($result, $array[$i]);
        $toBeat = $array[$i]['directors_count'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```